# Efficient solution for multiplayer space partioning?

Tags: multiplayer, performance, data, architecture, space-partitioning

This question is a little tricky, but I will try to make it clear.

Lets say I am building an online game (not MMO-scale), but that supports as many players as possible, in a authoritative server approach. I want really **big** worlds with **lots** of AI simulated enemies.

I am aware of a few strategies to save server CPU by subdividing the space and not processing what doesn't need processing. I have already split the world by regions, that will require loading times and small transitions, which I think is important to maintain the quality of gameplay when playing locally (alone or even with a couple of friends). I don't expect the players to be in more than one or two regions.

The problem is that a region can become pretty big, and have a lot of NPCs simulating at once. How do I handle this without affecting the players' experience? Approaches like one server per region and alike are not in the table.

I am mainly looking for data structures to hold hordes of enemies, and even peaceful NPCs. To finalize the question, please note that vehicles exist, therefore its considerably fast to travel within a region, influencing the "when" to cull areas.

Comment: Are you restricted to just one physical server?

Comment: Ultimately, no. But for the sake of both simpleness and achievability, for now, i can't complicate the project even more :)

Comment: Start simple.  Something like WoW that does operate on multiple physical boxes per "server" just divides up their world into a grid and all updating is based on who's in the same boxes as you.  Very simple, easy to tweak, works well and you can use it with just your one box to control processing.

Comment: I fully agree with your point of view, and maybe i missed something in my question. What if there is one player on the very right of the box' cell, and another in the very left of the right neighbour cell ? They should see each other! The world looks continues for a game like WoW.. This is what I don't understand, how to make a continuous world grid, while keeping it efficient? Certainly there are situations when players from two "servers" should see each other :)

Comment: Before asking the question, I was really tending to a quad-tree-like structure to insert the AI and a few more things, while leaving players  + vehicles to full processing.. Still doesn't look neat to me though.. Anyway, in a situation with a lot of players in one region, everything had to be simulated anyway... I guess I will make attempts in variable interval updating, even if the less important things fall a little behind :) Answers are welcome :D

Comment: Part of the solution is just game design.  There are some game concepts for which there are no technical solutions.  If you're trying to have "large regions" then a single player in each region will cause all of them to be active and the processing overload to be large.  Use smaller regions, and segment those regions with good map design so that you simply don't need to worry about a player in region A needing to "see" stuff in region C, with only a very small shared region B between them.  So far as general data structures, just about any hierarchical bounding volume/area approach will work.

Comment: And yeah, if you are going to have both a lot of stuff all over and a lot of players all over you really do have to plan for everything to be active everywhere and all the time, no magical way around that.  This is why single boxes of an MMO server group only service 200-500 players maximum AND why MMO AI for NPCs is pathetically stupid (aka cheap to compute).

Comment: Absolutely true, I will leave everything ready to encapsulate regions in different servers, its perfectly valid, but for now even 100 players is a over-expectation target! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand you will have some sort of physics running on your server.

If that's the case there are also other techniques available for AI/physics other than space partitioning. From most to less obvious:

- priority: NPCs with no direct interaction with players can receive less CPU time by lowering their refresh rate. You can use priority queues and run queues with the higher priority from first to last, while other queues will run only 1/2, 1/4 or 1/8 of the queue each cycle. this way you ensure each object runs at some point but you reduce the number of times it consumes CPU.
- physics can also be lowered (only the collision boxes and spheres can be used while roaming and away from sight).
- simplifying AI/simulation by allocating very basic behaviors to NPCs and environment while players are far away. Usually it will be roaming or scanning for enemies instead of hunting, gathering, farming...
- some physics and AI can also be delegated to the clients. If you really lack CPU on the servers you can tag object as being partially resolved and the clients will adjust the physics and position of those objects locally (to avoid floating NPCs). The clients can be given some responsibility in running AI (during combat against a player the targeted player's device can be directly running the attacking NPCs)
- for players, physics can also be lowered on the server and clients will receive more responsibility in collision resolution. Ex: you hit an object with your vehicle, the server will only solve the collision on the collision boxes and tag the objects as potentially in collision. The client will send the resolution to the server with a timestamp which will accept it if the objects are tagged and the solution seems right.

Once you have implemented these mechanisms you can decide how much and how often you need them. The great thing about this is that later you can add a few servers which will be able to take over some of the tasks instead of the client apps.

Of course the approximated collision detection will create some aberrations, but you will be able to solve them by adding more precision from time to time.

Also concerning physics you should have a look at libs which support some sort of [GPGPU](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpgpu) system like OpenCL or CUDA if you have access to a server which supports either.

Comment: Combining space partioning of a region with priority updates should be exactly what I need, optimal for little amounts of players, and still optimized when a lot of areas are loaded. Thanks.

Comment: @DevilWithin It should help, and it requires no changes on the client side. I also added a few more details to the answer.

Comment: The simplified AI is a wonderful idea. While the NPC are far from players, they don't need to be doing anything besides moving in most cases. That means I can just do an approximation of what they are up to, every 1 minute or something, just to make them roam around the world.. imagining them as zombies, they would do so!